# Color temperature and space

Tags: visible-light, temperature, thermal-radiation, stars

I often think about the universe and lately about the color spectrum. so I wanted to ask how much the temperature of the body depends on the color. the hottest star I've found is 200,000 k and its color is light blue.
our cooler sun is orange, you might say, and so on.
then what color would absolute zero represent? is it black color could it be deduced from this that even black holes have zero temperature or maybe they are even colder, but maybe we can't see such a color?
also interestingly, our suitable conditions for life are only (cca) 288 degrees Celsius warmer than absolute zero, and other objects in the universe can be several hundred thousand times hotter. so it can be said that our race is really cold-blooded. and also incredibly fragile.

Comment: You can toy around with [this](https://phet.colorado.edu/en/simulations/blackbody-spectrum) simulation of the so-called blackbody spectrum.

Comment: thanks, but it seems a bit imprecise to me. if the color black equaled absolute 0, it wouldn't be possible to see in space, right? so isn't it possible that black would correspond to an even colder temperature than absolute zero?

Comment: I don't understand this statement. The "color" black is the absence of light, so there is no wavelength of an electromagnetic wave that corresponds to black. But you can "see" black things when contrasted against non-black things, on Earth or in space. Finally, "an even colder temperature than absolute zero" does not make sense, see [this part of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_zero#Negative_temperatures).

Comment: Re, "...our cooler sun is orange, you might say..." That seems an odd thing to say. Why would you use some other star as your standard of "whiteness" instead of using the one star that has been our brightest source of illumination for almost the entire history of the human race? Rather than say that some other star many light years from here is "white" and our sun is relatively orange, I would say that our sun is the very definition of "white," and the other star is relatively blue.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is that "color" as you may be thinking of it, is something invented by our brain to help interpret the world. It doesn't really exist as a physical property. Frequency is the real property of light. When we talk about the color temperature of an object, we mean "what our eyes would see if we looked at it."

See this helpful video

https://youtu.be/-E6dxybpUvo

No temperature can be colder than absolute zero (0 K, –273.15°C), or even reach zero itself. Black holes have a thermal spectrum as predicted by Stephen Hawking, which depends on the black hole's mass, but for most black holes is extremely close to zero (very small fractions of Kelvin).

Comment: thank you, I will learn something about it